# Magento2 Rename "Company" attribute with custom name from Customer address

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, customer-attribute

I am customizing checkout fields and attributes for my client needs, and my client wants to Rename Company name with some other custom field, any idea from where i can change the company title?

Comment: are you want to change title only for checkout form or globally?

Comment: Globally. so the requirement was to get rid of Company field and create a new custom text field with custom name so instead of removing the company field and creating a new one, i am trying to rename the company field with custom name.